# Order by and limit on a multiple left join - PostgresSQL and python

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following relations:

- A Product have multiple Images
- A Product can have multiple Categories
- A Category can have multiple Products

I want to get:

- only the 'short_name' from the first category
- only the first image url order_by another parameter

I have the following SQL, in PostgreSql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(I.product_id) P.id, P.name, P.short_description,
       CAT.short_name AS category, I.url
FROM products_product AS P
LEFT JOIN products_product_categories AS RPC ON P.id = RPC.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories_category AS CAT ON RPC.category_id = CAT.id
LEFT JOIN products_productimage AS I ON I.product_id = P.id
WHERE (P.is_active = TRUE)
```

My issue is that I don't know to limit left join and order by, I try to add LIMIT 1

```
LEFT JOIN categories_category AS CAT ON RPC.category_id = CAT.id LIMIT 1
```

but it is not working, I receive a code error `'syntax error at or near "LEFT"`'

Category table

```
id | category_name | category_short_name
 1    catA                  A
 2    catB                  B
 3    catC                  C
```

Product  table

```
id | product_name | product_desc
 1    P1                  lorem1
 2    P2                  lorem2
 3    P3                  lorem3
```

ManytoMany: product_category

```
id  product_id category_id
1    1          1
2    2          1   
3    1          2
4    3          3   
5    3          3
```

Image table

```
id url product_id order
1  lo1    1       4 
2  lo2    1       0 
3  lo3    1       1
4  lo4    2       0
```

For Product with id1 I expect to get:

```
name: P1, desc 'lorem1', category short_name : cat A, image url lo2
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.) Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you spend too much time.

Comment: @jarlh I updated the code with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT ON` makes no sense without `ORDER BY`. As you want two different orders (on `i.order` for images and on `cat.id` for categories), you must do this in separate subqueries.

```
select p.id, p.name, p.short_description, c.short_name, i.url
from products_product p
left join
(
  select distinct on (pcat.product_id) pcat.product_id, cat.short_name
  from products_product_categories pcat
  join categories_category cat on cat.id = pcat.category_id
  order by pcat.product_id, cat.id
) c on c.product_id = p.id
left join
(
  select distinct on (product_id) product_id, url
  from products_productimage
  order by product_id, order
) i on i.product_id = p.id
where p.is_active
order by p.id;
```

Two alternatives to write this query are:

- subqueries with fetch first row only in the select clause
- lateral left joins on subqueries with fetch first row only

Comment: I used distinct on, as Limit 1 replacement, because I wanted just the first element

Comment: Yes, but `DISTINCT ON` works on a group, in your case the `product_id`. So you get the first row per `product_id`. Now you must define what the "first row" is. You do this with `ORDER BY`. Your query doesn't contain an `ORDER BY`, so `DISTINCT ON` is rather pointless (and I'm surprised it doesn't result in a syntax error even).